# Turn 2 dimensional excel table to filtered dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, multidimensional-array, dropdown

Can you help me figure out how to turn this table below into a filtered dropdown using reactjs.
I need to filter the result by age ( let's say the user is 33 years old) and show him the available options for his age group ( Capital to cover and monthly premium related to it ) then catch the data selected.

here is what I have accomplished so far:

1 - Turn the Excel table to CSV then using this website https://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/ I changed it to JSON ARRAY.
Here is a snippet of the result :

```
[["111.000 €","25 €","27 €","28 €","31 €","34 €"  ],["138.000 €","32 €","33€","35€","39 €","42 €"  ].... ]
```

2 - calculate the Age from birthdate then connect a function to identify the category to which the user belongs to. Note what I call Index is the index of the list item
ex: ["111.000 €","25 €","27 €","28 €","31 €","34 €"  ] the list starts at 0 , 1, 2 ...
corresponding to the column on the excel sheet.

```
getIndex = (age) => {
    let index = null;
    if (age < 25 ) {
        index = 1
    }
    if (age < 30 && age > 24) {
        index = 2
    }
    if (age < 40 && age > 29) {
        index = 3
    }
    if (age < 45 && age > 39) {
        index = 4
    }
    if (age > 45) {
        index = 5
    }
    this.setState({
        age_index : index
    })
};
```

3- I Use forEach to get separate items from the main list and generate a new list with only the parameters matching the index value.

```
createNewArrayLife = (listitem) => {
        if (this.state.age_index) {
           listitem.forEach((item) => {
               let data =  {
                   capital: item[0],
                   premium: item[this.state.age_index]
               };
               // Something is wrong from Here! ....
               this.setState({
                   life_insurance: [data, ...this.state.life_insurance]
               });
           });
        }
};
```

This is where I am hitting a little snag for some reason the state value only shows the last item ( it's like the list is not getting populated )

Any thoughts?

[Life_Insurance_price_table.jpg](https://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/)

Comment: Hi! Could you please show what you have tried already?

Comment: @FarrukhNormuradov I have turned the table to a JSON Array, following that I calculate the age then use a function with conditional statements to identify which category the user belongs to , then assign an Index based on age condition match . Next I use a foreach to create a new array containing only the parameters matching the age. and insert it to the Dropdown list, Am I getting any closer ?

Comment: Amazing, why do not you put your current solution here, so that others would use it to pin point the missing part?

Comment: @FarrukhNormuradov I posted some of the code can you have a look and tell me what am I missing here ?

Comment: Did you have a chance to try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Final view]

On my second reading I realised what you wanted to archive.
Here is my solution.
[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-fermat-jobuz?file=/src/App.js) is the environment.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { Component } from "react";

const insuranceTarifs = [
  ["111.000 €", "25 €", "27 €", "28 €", "31 €", "34 €"],
  ["138.000 €", "32 €", "33€", "35€", "39 €", "42 €"],
  ["238.000 €", "37 €", "39€", "41€", "43 €", "46 €"]
];

const persons = [
  { id: 1, name: "Igor", age: 11 },
  { id: 2, name: "Timur", age: 22 },
  { id: 3, name: "Dilshod", age: 35 },
  { id: 4, name: "Uktam", age: 43 },
  { id: 5, name: "Zarnigor", age: 56 }
];

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    life_insurance: []
  };

  handleOnAgeMatch = (calculation) => {
    if (
      !this.state.life_insurance.find(
        (element) => element.id === calculation.id
      )
    ) {
      this.setState({
        life_insurance: [calculation, ...this.state.life_insurance]
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const ageElements = persons.map((person) => (
      <li key={person.id}>
        <Person person={person} onAgeMatchHandler={this.handleOnAgeMatch} />
      </li>
    ));

    const pricePickers = this.state.life_insurance.map((list) => (
      <PricePicker userPricingList={list} />
    ));

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="item">
          <ul>{ageElements}</ul>
        </div>
        <div className="item">
          <ul>{pricePickers}</ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const PricePicker = ({ userPricingList }) => {
  const options = userPricingList.customPricingList.map((item) => (
    <option key={item.premium} value={item.premium}>
      {item.premium}
    </option>
  ));
  return (
    <li>
      <select id={userPricingList.id}>{options}</select>
    </li>
  );
};

const Person = ({ person, onAgeMatchHandler }) => {
  let index = null;
  const { age, id, name } = person;
  if (age < 25) {
    index = 1;
  }
  if (age < 30 && age > 24) {
    index = 2;
  }
  if (age < 40 && age > 29) {
    index = 3;
  }
  if (age < 45 && age > 39) {
    index = 4;
  }
  if (age > 45) {
    index = 5;
  }

  const userPricingList = [];
  insuranceTarifs.forEach((tarif) => {
    const data = {
      capital: tarif[0],
      premium: tarif[index]
    };
    userPricingList.push(data);
  });

  onAgeMatchHandler({ id, customPricingList: userPricingList });

  return (
    <div>
      {name} {age} y.o.
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Your answer is great although it does not match 100% my settings because I am using a setup that is a little more complex. Your handling of the forEach is perfect. I updated my question with the working function. Thanks a lot for your help .  You're the best

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Updated function based on @FarrukhNormuradov  Help.

```
createNewArrayLife = (listitem) => {
    const userPricingList = [];
    if (this.state.age_index) {
       listitem.forEach((item) => {
           const data = {
                capital: item[0],
                premium: item[this.state.age_index]
           };
           userPricingList.push(data);
       });
    }
    this.setState({
        life_insurance: userPricingList
    });
};
```